# Scatter plot overlaid map

Tags: matlab, maps, scatter-plot

I am wondering if it is possible for me to create a simple map with longitudes from 0 to 110'W and latitudes from 0 to 80'N overlaid with a scatterplot data of hurricane tracks using its lat/long coordinates. *Note, I only have Matlab student edition so the mapping toolbox is not included in my program. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Please come back when you have a [real question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) ...

Comment: How would I do that with the location information grouping by 10' lat and long bins, overlaid on map created in m_maps (http://www2.ocgy.ubc.ca/~rich/map.html)?